# reducir tamaño de todos los elementos de mi pagina angular para no tener que hacer zoom

Tags: angular, bootstrap, typescript, angular10

Buen Día, me gustaria saber si hay alguna posibilidad de que no tenga que bajar el zoom del navegador para ver mas reducido su contenido. la pagina principal me aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me han dicho que se ve muy grande que si puedo reducir los componentes ya que se ven muy grandes mas o menos para que se vea como esta imagen: (esta imagen lo tengo con un zoom al 67%)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco me puedan colaborar

Comment: Si usas `rem` como unidad de medida entonces puedes cambiar el `font-size` del `html` y eso ajustará los tamaños creando el efecto de alejamiento.

Comment: disculpa tienes algun ejemplo que pueda aplicar, es que lo eh intentado con el font-size pero para elementos como listas desplegables, div y demas elementos se me mantienen igual de grandes

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g1nxru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html . El `div` está medido en `rem`, al cambiar el `font-size` en el  `index.html` el tamaño del `div` se ajusta.

Comment: ya lo implemente pero solo me reduce lo que son textos, en efecto los div se ajustan pero lo que es la pagina se sigue viendo grande me explico, el nabvar, las listas desplegables los tabs y eso tambien me obligan a reducirlo

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste si están usando `rem` o `px`?

Comment: ya lo que pasa es que cree una clase css para asignarla al index y la estaba poniendo de manera incorrecta, te agredezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: Hace falta un [mcve] para poder determinar una forma de ayudarte. Saludos